# Click Once Update To Specific Version

Tags: c#, clickonce

I would like my users to be able to update to a specific version using click once.
Currently we have Help | Check for updates, which just updates to a latest version.

I'd like to add a Help | Update to version (which would then prompt for a version number that the user could enter and it would update them to that version (both if they are currently on a lower version or they are on a higher version)).

The application is developed using c#

- Note we want to do this via the application not outside of it, e.g. we know we can rollback via control panel etc... but what we want is facility within app to go to a specific version that is either higher or lower than current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve been able to get this functionality implemented with only a little additional work after each publish with no detailed instructions required by the user. The way this gets a specific version is that you need to have multiple clickonce directories for each version

After you publish you need to open the myApplication.application in notepad and make a change

```
<deploymentProvider codebase="http://www.example.com/ClickOnce/MyApplication/MyApplication.application" />
```

to

```
<deploymentProvider codebase="http://www.example.com/ClickOnce/MyApplication1.02.03.45/MyApplication.application" />
```

or whatever version you will be making available; before uploading to clickonce.

Here is how the user can get a specific version

```
    Public Shared Sub GetSpecificVersion()
            Try
                Dim spre As String = InputBox("press enter to download the current version of myApplication. If you would want to download a specific version of myApplication please append the version number  i.e myApplication1.02.03.45", , "myApplication") 
                Dim spost As String = "/myApplication.application"
                Dim finalUrl As String = "http://www.example.com/clickonce/"
                finalUrl = finalUrl & spre & spost
                Try
                    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(finalUrl, "C:/ProgramFiles", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 

1000, True) 'url/filename/username/password/showui/timeout/overwriteExiting
                Process.Start("C:/ProgramFiles/myApplication.application")
                Application.Current.Shutdown()
                Dim r As String
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("The desired version of myApplication may not be typed correctly or is unavailable on clickonce. alternatively a connection could not be established to the clickonce server")
                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```

To get the specific version all the user needs to do is to enter the version "myApplication1.02.34

a side effect of this is that checking for successive updates using the manifest will only check that specific folder, I created a second method for getting the latest version from a default directory:

heres to get central version

```
Public Shared Sub GetLatestCentralizedVersion()
Try
              My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/clickonce/myApplication/myApplication.application", "C:/ProgramFiles/myApplication.application", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 1000, True) 'url/filename/username/password/showui/timeout/overwrite
            Process.Start("C:/ProgramFiles/myApplication.application")
            Application.Current.Shutdown()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal but it can help if you're desperate enough to retrieve old binaries

1. Go to the ClickOnce server folder, it has a `setup.exe`, `publish.htm` `myapplicationname.application` among other files, it also has a folder named `Application Files`
2. In this `Application Files` folder you will find all previously ClickOnce uploaded versions
3. Copy / Download the folder for your version (named like `myapplicationname_1_2_30_145`)
4. Rename all files ending with "*.deploy" to remove that extension :

```sh
 find -type f -name '*.deploy' | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f%.deploy}"; done
```

Now you can basically use it like you would with a portable application, double click the executable or something

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting a limitation of ClickOnce, no way to do it. There's one manifest which must contain a single identity pointing to a server containing a version (new or old). Pointing the app to multiple versions won't work.

To provide a choice of versions you would need to do something outside of the ClickOnce infrastructure for your application, such as another app allowing the user to choose to install specific versions - this would be a very simple download a manifest type program and then permit the user to launch. Unfortunately each app would have to be made available from different locations with a different name, such as appending the version number.

Comment: I've found a way to do it similar to your suggestion. Going to stick code up here as answer once I have tested it, but we sort of have it working now.

Comment: By the way it doesn't require a separate app, we have this working from within our app.

Comment: @DermFrench Fair enough